# socketlabs not working without plainTextBody

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-8

This is working fine but when I am sending without `plainTextBody` then it's not working. I need to use without `plainTextBody`,  I need to set just `subject` and `htmlBody`.

When I am working without `plainTextBody` then it's not working.

```
$message->subject = "Simple Html file with text";
$message->plainTextBody = "This is the Plain Text Body of my message.";
$message->from = new EmailAddress("from@example.com");
$message->addToAddress(new EmailAddress("recipient1@example.com", "Recipient #1"));

//Get html content from a file
$pathToHtmlFile = __DIR__ .'../../../ExampleCode/Html/SampleEmail.html'; 
$message->htmlBody = file_get_contents($pathToHtmlFile);
 
//Send the message
$response = $client->send($message);
```

I am using this one `https://www.socketlabs.com/api/` but I do not want to use `plainTextBody` in our project.